# Мусор при отправке сообщений в чате

Tags: c#, сокет, кодировка, byte

Добрый день. Подскажите что не так делаю. 
Отправляю сообщение на с сервера к клиенту 
     `serverSocket.SendTo(Data, lenght,SocketFlags.None ,client);`
где
`Data` - массив Byte[1024]
`lenght` - длина передаваемого сообщения
`client` -  `IPEndPoint`
Клиент принимает:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // сообщение в тексте
    do
    {
      lengthInBytes = clientSocket.Receive(data);  // длина сообщения
      builder.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(data)); //data  - Byte[1024]
    } 
    while (clientSocket.Available > 0);
    commonWindow.Text += builder.ToString(); // вывод в TextBlock
```

Сообщение выводится в формате:
"Пользователь Иван вошел в чат [][][][][][][][][][][] и тд"
Видимо,  это пустые байтовые элементы, как их урезать? (судя по всему это надо делать при приеме сообщения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое возникает из-за того, что буфер заполняется не полностью и в нем остается мусор. Изменяйте длину вашего буфера после получения сообщения исходя из количества полученных байтов сообщения `received`.

```
Array.Resize(ref buffer, received);//ресайз буфера
strcontent = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);//получаем строку без мусора
Array.Resize(ref buffer, _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);//возвращаем буфер в исходное состояние
```

Comment: Ваш способ помог, вот только у меня непонятки остались. Как я понял из Вашего сообщения, делать ресайз буфера нужно только при приеме в клиенте, но по факту (в моем случае) нужно и на сервере и на клиенте. Почему так?